# Possible to explot link prefetching for loading HTML within document elements from remote files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing an interface with an accordian display style. When a given `div` within the accordion is expanded, it populates its `HTML` content from a remote file. When that `div` is shrunk, it populates its `HTML` content from a smaller remote file. Part of why I do this is that the large files are fairly large, and there is some lag when loading them. This way the page loads quickly initially. It has nothing to do with going easy on my server.

Is there a way to instruct the browser to prefetch and cache these files once it's loaded the main page? If not, what are some other workarounds? I like the idea of prefetching rather than an asynch call because it's possible a user won't open all `div` elements or will open them in an unpredictable order, so I'd rather not clog up bandwidth with `async` calls that may not be responding appropriately to user actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to leverage the [link prefetching API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) without worrying about rolling your own JavaScript.

For example, you can add the following line to the `<head />` of your document to prefetch a file's contents:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/big-file.txt" />
```

You can also supply that information in a `Link:` http header or a `<meta />` tag.

If you want to roll your own solution, you could load make a get request for all of the large documents immediately after the page loads and then load the smaller snippet after accordion is expanded for the first time.

Comment: I suppose my question is whether this link prefetching will be recognized/used when I'm loading remote HTML content via JavaScript rather than via browser navigation. Is that specified in the docs?

Comment: If you specify the proper cache headers on the resource it, it will be reused again.